# Curves: how to make circular shapes within curves

Tags: bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

Is there a way to make a "perfect" circle with the points of my nurbs circle (the ones around the cursor)?. I tried "as sphere" and "bend angle", but the results are not very satisfactory.

Ideally I'd be looking for something similar to the Loop Tools Add-on.

Alternatively I tried with adding more points to the shape I want to be circular, but it's fiddly, time consuming and not extremely precise...

[image: nurbs curve]

[image: nurbs circle 3d]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing that parametric curves have nothing to do with spheres.

[image: nurbs formula]
<sup>*Screenshoted frmo the preview of [An accurate NURBS curve interpolation algorithm with short spline interpolation capacity](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00170-012-4167-3)*</sup>

After you are satisfied with your curve you can utilize the [To Sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114050/30849) command. However, since it operate on points only, you have to do it **after** adding more points.

1. Duplicate your curve.
2. Instead of subdiving, remove the bevel, so the curve is only a curve. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Convert to mesh* to convert it to a mesh. The points on the curve are now sampled. Convert is back to a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Convert to curve*. Re-add your bevel settings.
3. If the center of your curve is at the world origin, move the 3D cursor to the origin and set it as the pivot point <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>.
4. Select all. <kbd>A</kbd>
5. Execute the *to sphere* command. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>